# Problem with precision in a python script

Tags: python

I need to convert numbers to a flat file format 0.57 becomes 000000000000000057 in this format (padding zeroes) My method

My method

```
def toAmount18(a):
   return str(int(a*100)).zfill(18)
```

For 0.57 it outputes 000000000000000056

The problem lies in a*100 it outputs 56.99999999999999 instead of 57. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [floating point accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/3545273) problem. In the early days of Fortran IV, we learned that the conversion from a float to an integer value was `I = F + .5`

Here you can still use the same trick:

```
def toAmount18(a):
   return str(int(a*100 + .5)).zfill(18)
```

or use more *modern* tools like `round`

```
   return str(round(a*100)).zfill(18)
```

The nice point with the manual method is that you can specify the *truncation magnitude* to your needs:

```
  return str(int(a*100 + .00005)).zfill(18)
```

will only round after the 4th decimal.

Comment: I tried to cast it to a decimal first which didn't help. We do not have this problem in c#. It seems pythons floating point precision isn't up to date :)

Comment: IEEE floating point is the same for all languages. But maybe C# has added some rounding magic at the last bits of the mantissa. As far as I am concerned, I prefere to decide myself which rounding I want to use than rely on a language feature, unless it is clearly documented (which is possible,  I do not use C#... )

Comment: C# complies with IEEE https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/ieee-floating-point-representation?view=msvc-160 interesting that 0.57 x 100 turns out 57 there. Need to investigate.

Comment: @Anders: The IEEE says nothing about how you convert a floating value to an int. But whatever the language `(0.57 * 100) < 57.0` will be true.

Comment: This is interesting in.NET5 0.57x100 is 56.9999 but in net core 3.1 its 57. This needs digging, they must have removed a automatic rounding in net 5. Oh well its out of scope for question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using int() as default works like a floor on the input number.

Try to use round() method instead of int() as shown in example:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/round

You can also add an extra security layer (try statement) which will handle wrong type exceptions.

Comment: round can lead to unwanted rounding though. We want truncate behavior of int 0,579 should still be treated as 57 on other end

Comment: like what? :D You missed something?

Comment: in this case, you can do something like this:
1) b = a * 100 - 57,9
2) c = floor(b) - now you got 57
3) d = b - c - here you got 0,9
4) e = b - d - now you got 57 again
You can simplify this operation and optimalise it with an if statement

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid maths altogether and invite regex to the party:

```
re.search(r'\.(\d{,2})', str(0.5)).group(1).zfill(18)
'000000000000000005'

re.search(r'\.(\d{,2})', str(0.57)).group(1).zfill(18)
'000000000000000057'

re.search(r'\.(\d{,2})', str(0.571)).group(1).zfill(18)
'000000000000000057'

re.search(r'\.(\d{,2})', str(0.579)).group(1).zfill(18)
'000000000000000057'
```

Might need some more sample inputs to get this tuned correctly for the expected output.